# Visual Studio Code can't open a folder on MacOS

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, finder

so I wanted to switch between projects in VSC on my MacBook Air (macOS Monterey) so, like usual, I went for a top bar, selected File, chose Open Folder. But then the Finder window that was prompted stopped responding for my touchpad clicks. It does respond when I try to crawl through folders with my keyboard but at the end I can't choose the folder to open. Any advice?

Comment: Presumably you have all your data backed up. You could try [Check if a Mac disk is about to fail](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp2548/mac).

Comment: The disk is fine. It would also be kind of strange for it to be not fine as this is a brand new macbook

Comment: I did not know that it's a new machine, but there is the [bathtub curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bathtub_curve) to be aware of. Now that that's out of the way, does it consistently go wrong with exactly one project or does it also go wrong with other projects?

Comment: It was going wrong with every project, however after a complete reboot of the machine the issue's gone. I think it might've been more of the VSC issue than Finder's.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also experiencing the same issue on my M1 Mac on OS Monterey 20.6 in other applications as well as VS Code. The only solution I found is the workaround posted here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253580300

Simply adjust the Finder window size by hovering the mouse over the corner/edge of the window then click & drag. This then makes the Finder window responsive to mouse clicks.